# How to get atoms with certain prefix from an atom family

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state, react-state-management, recoiljs

I am new to recoil and am trying to understand how to

1. retrieve atoms with certain key prefixes (e.g. "customerId-xyz") from an atom family – would I have to filter the productKeys every time by customerId in the component? That does not sound right.
2. retrieve all products for for a customer that have a certain value (e.g. size = S) from an atom family.

See the simplified setup below...

Thanks for your time!

```
export const productsAtom = atomFamily<Partial<Product>, string>({
    key: "productsAtom",
    default: {
        name: "",
        size: "",
    },
});


export const productKeysAtom = atom<string[]>({
    key: "productKeysAtom",
    default: [],
});

export const productsSelector = selectorFamily<
    Partial<Product>,
    string
>({
    key: "productsSelector",
    get:
        (productKey) =>
        ({ get }) => {
            return get(productsAtom(productKey));
        },
    set:
        (productKey) =>
        ({ set, get, reset }, updatedData) => {
            if (updatedData instanceof DefaultValue) {
                reset(productsAtom(productKey));

                set(productKeysAtom, (existingKeys) =>
                    existingKeys.filter((key) => key !== productKey),
                );

                return;
            }

            set(productsAtom(productKey), (product) => {
                return {
                    ...product,
                    ...updatedData,
                };
            });

            const productKeys = get(productKeysAtom);

            if (!productKeys.includes(productKey)) {
                set(productKeysAtom, (keys) => [...keys, productKey]);
            }
        },
});
```

Comment: (1) That's exactly how you'd do it, and that's what the [`waitFor...`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/utils/waitForAll) APIs are for. (2) Use a `selectorFamily` just like in your example.